# Duplicate Error while generating signed release apk

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to generate Release SignedApk but not getting successful. but in debug mode, it's working fine.

In Release mode the following error occurs: -

`[raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_feather] /Users/sourav/backup/STMSParent/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_feather.json    [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_feather] /Users/sourav/backup/STMSParent/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_feather.json: Error: Duplicate resources
[raw/app] /Users/sourav/backup/STMSParent/android/app/src/main/res/raw/app.json [raw/app] /Users/sourav/backup/STMSParent/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/app.json: Error: Duplicate resources
[raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome] /Users/sourav/backup/STMSParent/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome.json [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome]`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Go to this folder

> ~/android/app/src/main/res/raw/

Delete all the files in there.

Now try to

```
$  cd android
$ ./gradlew clean
$ ./gradlew bundleRelease
```

This works for me...